# Migration from TFS 2005 to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

I have installed TFS 2010 on a new server (vmware running windows server 2008 r2) and restored from backup my old TFS 2005 Database onto the new server. The installation seems to have succeeded - I can create a **NEW** TFS 2010 team project and I can do checkin/checkout for it.

I made a mistake, however, with the TFS 2010 configuration manager - I ran the advanced configration wizard and **NOT** the upgrade wizard.
Now I don't see my old TFS 2005 team project and the upgrade wizard is now disabled.
In order to fix my mistake I tried this:

```
TFSServiceControl quiesce

tfsconfig import /sqlInstance:MyServer\DBinstanceName /collectionName:MyImported /confirmed
```

This is the output of this commands:

```
TF255152: Service is not running: TFSJobAgent
The upgrade of the project collection MyImported has been queued.
Waiting on the upgrade operation to complete.
```

...and now I am waiting for too much time for this operation to complete (my version control DB is 15 GB).

How can I import my old TFS 2005 team project to the new TFS 2010 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you [go](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2010/03/15/tfs-2010-in-place-upgrade-of-tfs-2005-to-tfs-2010.aspx) it supports inplace upgrades...

Comment: by the way i need migration and not in place upgrae , i see that there is a link for migration also, but now the upgrade wizard is disable for me, is there is a fast way to run it or do i need to do repair of the TFS 2010 instalation in order for this upgrade wizard to be enable again?

Comment: did you try this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2010/03/01/tfs-2010-quick-peak-on-tfs-2008-to-tfs-2010-upgrade-migration-upgrade.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do a migration and it is currently jacked up then I would simply start from scratch.  You'll spend far less time doing this than trying to fix the issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose an install (advance configuration wizard in your case) instead of an upgrade, what happens is that new configuration and default collection databases are created for you, and your restored 2005 databases are not touched.

The safest way to deal with this issue is, like Chris suggested, to start from scratch. You wouldn't need to restore your 2005 databases again though, all you need to do is to uninstall TFS, make sure the new Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection databases got deleted, and reinstall TFS and configure again with the Upgrade wizard. Installing TFS 2010 should be fast.